# Post Should Redirect to Different Page

Tags: angular, redirect, routes, http-post

I have a post call which should post some content to a URL, after that redirect should happen, I am seeing the redirect urls and getting the correct data in console-> network, but Page is not getting redirected.

Tried to access the header of the response, where it specifies redirect url in 'location' , but could not access header too.

Location    /abs/Redirect?clientId=abc

My redirect url should be the value from location key mentioned above from response header from my Post.

This is my code for post.

```
const test= this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ Req: req 
})).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data);
       }
     );
```

Can anyone help me how to access header of the response from Post, or directly allow redirect. I am using angular 6.

Comment: do you want to redirect to a route defined in router module?

Comment: No I have to redirect to the url which I got in response header of the Post.

Comment: are you able to access `url` mentioned in response directly by entering it in `address bar`?

Answer (score 0):

As @varundhariyal pointed out, the Router wont work like that for external links. A ***workaround*** is to use: 
`window.location.href= yourURL`

---

If the URL you want is in the response then you can try something like this:

Define a Router instance in you constructor:

`constructor(private route: Router)`

*(you will need to import it: `import { Router } from '@angular/router';`)*

and use it to navigate to the wanted url in your subscription response:

```
const test= this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify({ Req: req })).subscribe(
  data => {
    this.route.navigate(data.url);   //Only works for routes defined in the RouterModule

    window.location.href = data.url; //Absolute path to any URL
  }
);
```

Comment: I am not able to access any properties of 'data'.

Comment: You said "I am seeing the redirect urls and getting the correct data in console", what is the console printing as your data?

Comment: this method will not work! as there is no route defined,Router only work for routes already present in `routermodule`